# Get repository name from the form class

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to use repository name inside the form class so that I can create fields based on ORM models. How can I do that?

I'm asking this question because this form class is universal for a couple of repository classes.

This is how I wanna create the form:

```
$builder->add($field_name, 'entity', [
                'class' => 'TestBundle:'.$something, // entity name should go here
                'property' => $field_name,
                'disabled' => true,
                'data' => $data,
            ]);
```

And this method sits in the `TestBundle\Form\Type` namespace form class. How can I do that? I also have the access to `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('TestBundle:Repo')` in that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be specified as mandatory option of your form type:

```
class MyType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add(..., [
            'class' => 'TestBundle:' . $options['repository_name'],
            ...
        ]);
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setRequired(['repository_name']);
    }
}
```

Later, when you'll be creating a form, you'll have to use it this way:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyType(), $someData, [
    'repository_class' => 'Abcdef'
]);
```